# How to control or manipulate a server using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to manipulate my own custom http server using javascript.

For example I would like the server to send an email based on ajax data received from a javascript page hosted from the server.

Another use would be to open a connection at an arbitrary port to an arbitrary web address and receive data from the connection.

Is there a protocol or framework to do this ?

Comment: yeah, node.js. look it up

Comment: @KaiQing: Who says his webserver runs on Node already? He needs a SSPL, and Node.JS could be one possibility. However, it depends on his webhosting.

Comment: You should explore and use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for this.

Comment: @sebastien - he should not choose his programming language based on what his web host offers. If he needs node and they don't support it then he has to choose a host that does or change the expectations of his project. Anyhow, you derived quite a bit from a simple comment. In the end, with little effort he could achieve what he needs with node.

Comment: @KaiQing: "yeah, node.js. look it up". That's the original derivation. Node is not, by far, the only thing that allows you to handle arbitrary directives from an incoming HTTP request, and saying "node" without mentioning that there is a plethora of other solutions is narrow-minded, to say the least.

Comment: @sebastien - Yeah? and how narrow minded is criticizing someone that suggested one without in turn suggesting any of the plethora you allude to?

Comment: @KaiQing: I have done exactly this in my answer: mentioned that he will need a server-side processing language, and that two possible ideas would be Node.JS and PHP, pointing out drawbacks and advantages for each... and mentioned that if he only knew JS, sticking with Node might be a better pick. What exactly did I *not* say?

Comment: @sebastien - huzzah! I did not see you had answered. I retract my assault. and casually plus on the way out. Good day sir!

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld, the OP's question to _the community_ asks... "Is there a protocol or framework to do this ?" ...it's NOT narrow minded to suggest `node.js` as one of many, even if you don't say "it's one of many". It may be the one framework the answerer knows and therefore has every right to suggest. To say that's "narrow minded" would mean that 90% of the answers given at SO are narrow minded answers, since most participants of a question do not list _the_ plethora of ways to accomplish a task. They specify the one they know. Don't be judgmental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used all the keywords and know all the techs you need to use:

- You need AJAX to allow JavaScript to asynchronously connect to (and interact with) your webserver
- You'll need a server-side processing language to do all the emailing business

The way you will do it will inevitably depend on the language. For example, if you're using PHP, the `mail()` function provides a simple way to send email... whilst the HTTP requests you speak of can sometimes get rather hairy.
A server-side environment like Node provides the opposite. Mails are hard to send - HTTP requests are trivial.

If you only know JS, I recommend you stick to Node, which takes JS scripts as directives.